# How to make a time limit for answer in python game with GUI?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am making a game that requires from a user to type a proper phylum, based on a given photo of a species. I provide a GUI for my game. Currently, I am struggling to limit the time that user have to give his answer. I tried with Timer (threading), but idk how to cancel a thread when user doesn't exceed a maximum time.
Here is my code for the button that is used to confirm answer:

```
  time_answer = 10
    def confirm_action():
        global img_label, answer, n
        from_answer = answer.get().lower()
        if n == len(files) - 1:
            answer_check(from_answer, round_up(end - start, 2))
            confirm.configure(text="Done")
            answer.configure(state=DISABLED)
            n += 1
        elif n == len(files):
            root.quit()
        else:
            answer_check(from_answer, "(Press shift)")
            answer.bind("<Shift_L>", insert_text)
            n += 1
            img_f = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(f"program_ib_zdjecia/faces/{directories[n]}/{files[n]}"))
            img_label.configure(image=img_f)
            img_label.image = img_f
            t = Timer(time_answer, confirm_action)
            t.start()
    
    confirm = Button(root, text="Confirm", command=confirm_action)
```

Comment: research tkinter's `after` method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [@Bryan Oakley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7432/bryan-oakley) said, you can use `tkinter`'s `after()` method to set a timer that disables user input, but only if the user doesn't submit input within the certain amount of time.

I'll have the explanations here, and a simple example will be at the bottom.

---

### Setting a timer using `after()`

First, how to set a timer using `after()`. It takes two arguments:

1. The number of milliseconds to wait before calling the function, and
2. The function to call when it's time.

For example, if you wanted to change a label's text after 1 second, you could do something like this:

```py
root.after(1000, lambda: label.config(text="Done!")
```

### Canceling the timer using `after_cancel()`

Now, if the user *does* submit the input within the given amount of time, you'll want some way of cancelling the timer. That's what `after_cancel()` is for. It takes one argument: the string id of the timer to cancel.

To get the id of a timer, you need to assign the return value of `after()` to a variable. Like this:

```py
timer = root.after(1000, some_function)
root.after_cancel(timer)
```

---

### Example

Here's a simple example of a cancel-able timer using a button. The user has 3 seconds to press the button before it becomes disabled, and if they press the button before time is up, the timer gets canceled so that the button never gets disabled.

```py
import tkinter

# Create the window and the button
root = tkinter.Tk()
button = tkinter.Button(root, text="Press me before time runs out!")
button.pack()

# The function that disables the button
def disable_button():
    button.config(state="disabled", text="Too late!")

# The timer that disables the button after 3 seconds
timer = root.after(3000, disable_button)

# The function that cancels the timer
def cancel_timer():
    root.after_cancel(timer)

# Set the button's command so that it cancels the timer when it's clicked
button.config(command=cancel_timer)

root.mainloop()
```

If you have any more questions, let me know!

Comment: Thanks! You're a life-saver. However, is there any possibility to obtain the same/similar result using threads? I also tried a different approach than the one submitted, where I firstly created a thread outside the function and then call it. This way I could check whether the thread is active (is_alive()) and if so, cancel it. Unfortunately, it turned out that it's not possible to restart a thread in python. Asking out of curiosity.

Comment: @MateuszKonat Well, it might be _possible_, but threads and GUIs don't go well together. If you put any `tkinter` code in a separate thread, it causes error messages. Using `after()` is the better way to go when it comes to timers. However, you _can_ use threads when you have a time-consuming, GUI-unrelated function to run (like gathering info from a database), and you don't want it to freeze the GUI. That's where threads are really helpful.

Comment: I'm very thankful for resolving my doubts!